# Why aren't oldschool skateboard tricks seen much today with modern skateboards?

Tags: equipment, history, technique, skateboarding

Why are skateboard tricks like those seen in this video (starting at 13:30) not seen much anymore, at least not with modern boards?

The kinds of tricks I'm referring to are handstands, hand flips with the board, other fliptricks that aren't based on ollies, style heavy on spins pivots and slides, etc.

https://youtu.be/STqE9JXgKJU?t=13m30s

Are modern boards not suitable for these kind of old school tricks and style or have skaters and skating simply changed? If the boards are not suitable, what specifically stops people from getting into this kind of thing? Weight, material, shape and of deck, wheels, trucks, risers, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this has nothing to do with how the skateboards looks, but has merely got to do with the evolution of skateboarding and trends.

Looking at the skateboards in the videos, some boards look quite wide, and I would say it's less common this day to ride on a 11 inches wide board than it was back then (the film is from 1987). However, I think it would even be easier to perform the tricks in question with a smaller, lighter board, so I don't think this is the answer.

My theory is that as more skate ramps and parks were built, people started to get used to more flow and high speed, and flat ground skating became less popular. This could have made the more acrobatic tricks seem outdated and as a break of the flow.

Comment: Was about to guess something in the same area. Basically, people came up with new tricks, learned to use how skateparks are created to get more speed and do better tricks, so old tricks became phased out. My other guess would have been that old tricks would have become cliché, like 'weve seen a 720 spin before, it's not new and amazing anymore' and thats why skaters do not go for those in competition anymore.